# как разрешить скроллить recyclerview до последнего элемента?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Использую в приложении RecyclerView и FAB. Проблема в том, что кнопка FAB закрывает некоторые элементы управления в последнем элементе списка RecyclerView. Выход из ситуации вижу так, чтобы разрешить скроллить список таким образом, чтобы могли уходить наверх все элементы, кроме последнего. А по-умолчанию, последний элемент списка не скроллится выше нижнего края RecyclerView. Как изменить это поведение?
PS: скрытие кнопки FAB тоже не подходит, когда в списке всего два элемента: они оба влезают на экране и ничего никуда не скроллится, при этом FAB закрывает часть последнего элемента.

Comment: Если следовать логике то фаб - плавающая кнопка обязана плавать, тоесть при скроллинге вниз фаб должен нырять а при скроллинге вверх всплывать обратно. привычно, прикольно и со смыслом. Это легко реализовать анимациями.

Comment: Можно доработать адаптер, чтобы показать еще один прозрачный элемент в конце списка.

Comment: @СергейГрушин нет готового примера? я такое видел, и даже, наверное, сделаю. но то, что приходит на ум, "легко" не называется.

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос чтобы люди быстро находили ответ, если захотят сделать так же

Answer (score 0):

Корневым элементом разметки должен быть `CoordinatorLayout`. Создаете класс `Behavior` для кнопки `FAB`

```
public class FABScrollBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {

public FABScrollBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet){
    super();
}
@Override  
public void onNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton child, View target, int dxConsumed, int dyConsumed, int dxUnconsumed, int dyUnconsumed) { 
  super.onNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target, dxConsumed, dyConsumed, dxUnconsumed, dyUnconsumed); 
  if(dyConsumed > 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){ 
     child.hide(); 
  } else if(dyConsumed < 0 && child.getVisibility() == View.GONE){ 
     child.show(); 
  }  
} 
@Override 
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, FloatingActionButton child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) { 
  return nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL; 
}
}
```

И в тэг `FloatingActionButton`

```
app:layout_behavior="your.package.FABScrollBehavior"
```

Теперь при скроллинге вниз фаб будет сжиматься масштабированием к центру, а при скроллинге вверх - разжиматься обратно. Можете заменить это на анимации нырка и всплывания. Найдите в коде методы `show()` и `hide()` и все поймёте

Поделюсь пожалуй полным макетом

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                          android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                          app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                          android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
                          android:background="#831296">
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
      </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/fabRVlist"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:listSelector="#00000000"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

      <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/facb"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                app:layout_anchor="@+id/fabRVlist"
                app:layout_behavior="ru.albatros.material.FABScrollBehavior"
                android:src="@drawable/fabrandom"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"
      />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Оставляю ссылку на свой гитхаб репозиторий, в нем я собрал все такие штуки и поюзал все виджеты из `design.support.library`

http://github.com/ATumbler/Material-Demos

Answer (score 0):

Варианты:

1. По достижении последнего элемента или когда все элементы помещаются на экран, перемещайте FAB к верхней границе списка;
2. Дайте юзеру возможность перемещать FAB по экрану, чтобы он сам его подвинул куда нужно;
3. Учитывая, что оба варианта выше не решают проблему, а дают чуть больше гибкости, но могут раздражать юзера, можно ещё спрятать FAB вообще, а в подвале списка развернуть что-то вроде панели инструментов с содержимым FAB. Для андроид не типично "доставать" что-то из-под нижнего края экрана, однако можно эту панель прятать и вытягивать как раз из-под нижнего края списка.

Понимаю, что костыли, однако гибкость управления интерфейсом - это, скорее, фича.

Comment: Зачем такие костыли если есть стандартное поведение, при котором fab исчезает при скролинге списка вниз?

Comment: Я добавил к списку призрачный элемент в конец высотой чуть больше FAB

Comment: @temq перечитайте всю информацию автора. Речь идёт о том, что даже когда список помещается на экране (скроллинг не требуется) - фаб мешает. Когда список длинный и скроллинг дошёл до последнего элемента - фаб, опять же, мешает.